# Dialogue box in jQuery not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my dialogue box code which using jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       function showDialog() {
        $("#Close").dialog({
            resizable: true,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            position: 'center',
            buttons: {
                'Yes': function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return true;
                },
                'No': function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    };

    $('#Open').click(function(){
    alert('Hellp');
    //    showDialog();
    });
});
```

But does is not working? Here is my jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zjRga/349/

Comment: I would suggest naming your divs something other than open and close - it really confused me as I assumed they were buttons. Posting your html here would help too.

Answer (score 4):

In your code you never actually *invoke* the dialog.  Notice this:

```
alert('Hellp');
//    showDialog();
```

You're showing a standard `alert` instead of calling your `showDialog` function.  When I swap out those lines as comments [in your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zjRga/350/), it seems to work:

```
//alert('Hellp');
showDialog();
```

Comment: after your suggestion it worked in jsfiddle but not in my site

Comment: @SanjayRathod: Then clearly something else is wrong on your site, and you're not sharing enough information for anybody here to determine what.  The code in the question works fine when you un-comment the part that you want to execute.  Can you reproduce the error on your site in the question or in a jsFiddle?

Comment: it shows this error - TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
 

'No': function () {

Comment: @SanjayRathod: If `dialog` is not a function then you haven't loaded the jQuery UI library.  Nothing to do with your code, you're just not including the necessary resources.

Comment: i have loaded - <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: @SanjayRathod: You claim you have, the web browser's JavaScript engine claims you haven't.  I'm inclined to believe one of these more than the other.  For starters, those `src` values (at least as they display here) don't include the leading `//` so I'd expect you're getting `404` errors on them.  Check your browser debugging tools to make sure the actual references are, in fact, being loaded as you expect.

Comment: @SanjayRathod: The main point here is that you're asking for help with a problem that you haven't been able to demonstrate.  The code in your question works, the code in your jsFiddle works.  Some other code somewhere else that you haven't shared with us doesn't work.  We can't help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you may need to check the tags. They are perfectly close. Hence, I would like to suggest you check the opening and closing tags. Meanwhile I have checked your code jsfiddle and make necessary adjustments.

You can check this here [http://jsfiddle.net/zjRga/353/]